# Select minimum number of rows from a matrix to fill all columns?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I'm going to buy LEGO bricks for a project of mine. I want to figure out the cheapest way to buy them from multiple sellers.

Let the rows of a matrix represent a seller and the columns of that matrix represent whether a given seller has that type of brick in the inventory or not. How do I pick the minimum number of rows from that matrix, so that all columns are non-zero in at least one row; i.e. how do I select columns 4,5 from the matrix below?

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
      1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am very happy to just receive an answer to my first question, but I'll go a bit further anyway. What if a seller is only able to fill a fraction of my order for a specific brick type. Let the matrix cells represent fractions. How do I identify rows 1,2,3,4 in the matrix below?

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.34 & 0.34  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.34 & 0.34  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.34 & 0.34 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.1 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.1 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
    \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm happy with an answer to the first question, but I'll go even further. Most of the time a seller can fill my order for each type of brick, so I am more interested in their price for each type of brick. Now the matrix cells represent summed prices. How do I identify rows 1,2,3 in the matrix below?

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
      2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

And finally there is shipping cost associated with each purchase. What if I had to factor that in? If vector B represents shipping costs, how would I identify rows 5,6 below as the cheapest option (cost 14), whereas rows 1,2,3 cost 15?

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
      2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    \\
  \end{bmatrix}
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3 \\
      3 \\
      3 \\
      1 \\
      1 \\
    \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm happy to be pointed to the literature instead of receiving an answer to my first question. I might actually prefer that. I am not a mathematician and I haven't done matrix calculations for a number of years. My question could therefore be very simple and it is possible, that I can solve it myself, if someone points me in the right directions. Thanks.

Comment: I am currently reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm